# Case insensitive filter using mongodb $in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to make case insensitive filter using mongodb query . my code -

```
var brand = req.query['Brand'].split(',');            
query['genetal.brand'] =  {$in:brand};
```

i am not able to add /^ / regex in every $in item.Or is there any other method to find .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[RegExp object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** to create a regular expression from a string. You need to first update the string to include pipes, i.e. create a regex match that replaces comma with a pipe and then in your find query use one regex, not an array of them, like `[/a|b|c/i]`.

To illustrate the above with mongo shell:

```
// insert test documents
db.product.insert({x: "A"});
db.product.insert({x: "b"});
db.product.insert({x: "c"});
db.product.insert({x: "d"});
db.product.insert({x: "e"});

var brands = "a,b,c";
var pipe = brands.replace(/[ ]*,[ ]*|[ ]+/g, "|") // same as var pipe = "a|b|c";
var re = new RegExp(pipe, "i"); // same as var re = /a|b|c/i;
db.product.find({"x": {"$in": [re]}});
```

**Returns**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("552b7c869c752469483ce9c2"),
    "x" : "A"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("552b7c869c752469483ce9c3"),
    "x" : "b"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("552b7c869c752469483ce9c4"),
    "x" : "c"
}
```

So you final code should look like:

```
var pipe = req.query['Brand'].replace(/[ ]*,[ ]*|[ ]+/g, "|");  
var re = new RegExp(pipe, "i");          
query['genetal.brand'] = {"$in": [re] };
```